# Not able to update Big query table with Transfer from a Storage file

Tags: google-bigquery, storage, transfer

I am not able to update a big query table from a storage file.  I have latest data file and transfer runs successfully. But it say "8:36:01 AM  Detected that no changes will be made to the destination table.".
Tried multiple ways.
 Please help.
Thanks,
-Srini

Comment: For anyone to help you, we will need a lot more context.

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait 1 hour after your file has been updated in Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer?hl=en_US#minimum_intervals

I had the same error. I created two transfers from GCS to BigQuery, with write preference set to MIRROR and APPEND. I got the logs below (no error). The GCS file was uploaded less than one hour before.

- MIRROR: Detected that no changes will be made to the destination table. Summary: succeeded 0 jobs, failed 0 jobs.
- APPEND: None of the 1 new file(s) found matching "gs://mybucket/myfile" meet the requirement of being at least 60 minutes old. They will be loaded in next run. Summary: succeeded 0 jobs, failed 0 jobs.

Both jobs went through one hour later.

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date, on the link it now says: `Source files are picked up for transfer immediately, with no minimum file age.`