# BigQuery - Data transfer "Detected that no changes will be made to the destination table"

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I use a script to generate files from an API and store them on Google Cloud Storage. Following this documentation, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer?hl=en_US#limitations, I've created a BigQuery table with the corresponding schema in advance and t then created a Data Transfer with the following configuration:

[image]

When I run the Data Transfer the following error shows up in the logs:

> Detected that no changes will be made to the destination table

I've updated some of the files, added files, deleted files, etc and everytime I get the same message. I also have other Data Transfers that work just fine with the same BigQuery instance and Cloud Storage bucket.

Only issue I found on SO, [Not able to update Big query table with Transfer from a Storage file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126019/not-able-to-update-big-query-table-with-transfer-from-a-storage-file), says you need to wait 1 hour, but even after a day I get the same error.

Any idea as to what triggers BiQuery to determine changes have been made (or not)?

Comment: could you confirm if you're still facing this issue? Have you checked all the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer?hl=en_US#limitations) while implementing GCS transfer?

Comment: I'm still facing the issue and have already checked the limitations. Didn't see any red flags there. Are you suggesting that the error could be something different to what the log message points to?

Comment: Generally when new version of files are uploaded to GCS these source files in Cloud Storage need to be at least one hour old to get picked up by the [transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer?hl=en_US#minimum_intervals).

Comment: But you are still facing this error after 24hrs. It seems there is some internal issue with your environment. Hence I would advise to open a Cloud [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) or an issue on [IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your situation so that issue can be checked internally.